How to create android studio plugin to add samples to android studio's list of sample projects
Is it possible to create an android studio plugin that adds your own custom samples to the list of downloadable samples provided by android studio? So far, I have only seen plugins with actions and templates creation but I need to add sample projects too not just templates. Any guides or documentation to achieve this will be much appreciated. Thanks

Absolutely! Creating custom samples for the Android Studio plugin is fantastic. To create Android Studio plugins, we need to use IntelliJ IDEA CE (or IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate). I have some blogs and links that help you well.

trycatchdebug.net

This is a sample step-by-step guide.
Not much content to understand.


sasikanth.dev

Showing how we can build an Android Studio plugin to provide our project templates in the Android Studio new project wizard.
Plugin to create a List/Detail App available on GitHub.
Follow the git repo for understanding and read the blog. If you face some problems then visit a comment section because solutions are also available there.



I hope this helps you well.
